# Check if won in Tic Tac Toe 2D array c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

Console App C#

I made a 2D array to represent a grid for the game. I cant find a way to check if the player has won.
I tried many things and searched online and I cant find it
I tried to loop thru the grid and check each one of the elements inside that row/column
I would love to get the explanation of why its not working and how to do it instead of the code answer.

```
public static void Win_check()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x')
        {
            gameStatus = 'x';
        }

        if (grid[2, i] == 'o' && grid[2, i] == 'o' && grid[2, i] == 'o')
        {
            gameStatus = 'o';
        }

        if (grid[3, i] == 'o' && grid[3, i] == 'o' && grid[3, i] == 'o')
        {
            gameStatus = 'o';
        }

        if (grid[i, 1] == 'x' && grid[i, 1] == 'x' && grid[i, 1] == 'x')
        {
            gameStatus = 'x';
        }

        if (grid[i, 2] == 'o' && grid[i, 2] == 'o' && grid[i, 2] == 'o')
        {
            gameStatus = 'o';
        }

        if (grid[i, 3] == 'o' && grid[i, 3] == 'o' && grid[i, 3] == 'o')
        {
            gameStatus = 'o';
        }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question please explain the problem more than just "it's not working". I can say from the code you've posted that `grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x'` is checking the same thing 3 times, which is probably not what you want

Comment: The index might should be 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3

Comment: `grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x' && grid[1, i] == 'x'` You are repeating the same condition three times...

Comment: sorry for not giving u more detail



` const int rows = 3;
        const int columns = 3;
        static char[,] grid = new char[rows, columns];`

Comment: @oryam Use a switch statement (it's more optimized).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *enumerating* all the lines which bring win: **3** horizontal, **3** vertical and finally **2** diagonals.

```
private static IEnumerable<char[]> Lines(char[,] field) {
  char[] result;

  int size = Math.Min(field.GetLength(0), field.GetLength(1));

  for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
    result = new char[size];

    for (int c = 0; c < size; ++c)
      result[c] = field[r, c];

    yield return result;
  }

  for (int c = 0; c < size; ++c) {
    result = new char[size];

    for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r)
      result[r] = field[r, c];

    yield return result;
  }

  result = new char[size];

  for (int d = 0; d < size; ++d)
    result[d] = field[d, d];

  yield return result;

  result = new char[size];

  for (int d = 0; d < size; ++d)
    result[d] = field[d, size - d - 1];

  yield return result;
}
```

Then you can easily query these lines with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static bool IsWon(char[,] field, char who) {
  return Lines(field).Any(line => line.All(item => item == who));
}
```

For instance:

```
  char[,] field = new char[,] {
    { 'x', 'o', 'o'},
    { 'x', 'o', ' '},
    { 'o', 'x', 'x'},
  };

  // Is field won by x?
  Console.WriteLine(IsWon(field, 'x') ? "Y" : "N");
  // Is field won by o?
  Console.WriteLine(IsWon(field, 'o') ? "Y" : "N");
```